# Issue with catching my selection input

Tags: java, input, exception

I am creating a program that is a simple mock-up of a banking account system. I have a simple method that when called asks the user to input a name (String) and a starting account balance (double) and creates a new Person object / Account object.

This method is called via a menu that uses 1-9 (int) options, and say '1' is pressed to create a new account. So the code (before accepting the string) has a default input.nextLine(); command to catch the int input before capturing the actual name input (customerName = input.nextLine();).

The issue I am having is that I am trying to add exception handling to this method to ensure that the name String input is only letters and spaces. When running the first time and someone puts an incorrect input, it would re-output the "Please input a name" but then they would have to enter the name twice since the input.nextLine(); was still in there (but not catching a menu input). So I added a if/else decision structure with a counter for the first time that the program runs if the (counter == 0) then it keeps the input.nextLine() and increments the counter, but if the (counter > 0) it gets rid of the input.nextLine() so that the program runs fine.

This causes another problem, that if the user tries to create multiple accounts, it will cause the program to stop printing the input.nextLine() the second time it is called and automatically assume the menu option input is what the name is supposed to be, and sends an error. Is there a better way to get this working the way I intended?

Sorry if the description isn't very clear, it's a hard problem to describe.

Here's the code:

```
public void menuOptionOne() {
    do {
        try {
            if (counter == 0) { // counter is initially set to 0
                System.out.println("Please input the customer's name: ");
                input.nextLine(); // catches the menu input
                customerName = input.nextLine();
                matcher = pattern.matcher(customerName);
                counter++; // increments the counter in case the user's input is invalid
                if (!matcher.find()) { // if it has non-letter/space characters present, throws exception
                    throw new Exception("Try again. (Incorrect input: name must contain only letters)");
                }
            } else if (counter > 0) { // asks the user to input name again, without the input.nextLine() which is intended to catch the menu int input
                System.out.println("Please input the customer's name: ");
                customerName = input.nextLine();
                matcher = pattern.matcher(customerName); // checks the input to ensure it is only letters and/or spaces
                if (!matcher.find()) {
                    throw new Exception("Try again. (Incorrect input: name must contain only letters)");
                }
            }
            continueInput = false;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    } while (continueInput);
```

So when this gets called twice in a row, it automatically goes to the second decision structure, without the input.nextLine(), and that catches the menu input (1) and throws the exception. How can I get it to work properly each time the method is called?

This is the output when it is called twice in a row (note: it saves the menu input as the new customer name, even though it is a number):

```
Please input the customer's name: 
java.lang.Exception: Try again. (Incorrect input: name must contain only letters)
Please enter the new balance:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do two things in the input retrieval:

- allow a series of inputs by reusing this method.
- check the content of the input and start again if not suitable.

The way you are using to "allow a series of inputs by reusing this method" is the source of your error.
In a general way you should favor the use of the most restricted scope when it is enough.
By declaring `continueInput` and `counter` as a field variable instead of a local variable you create a coupling between invocations of `menuOptionOne()`.
Which explain your problem :

> This causes another problem, that if the user tries to create multiple
>   accounts, it will cause the program to stop printing the
>   input.nextLine() the second time it is called and automatically assume
>   the menu option input is what the name is supposed to be, and sends an
>   error. Is there a better way to get this working the way I intended?

This code should be enough :

```
public void menuOptionOne() {

    // change
    int counter = 0;
    boolean continueInput = true;
    // end change

    do {
        try {
            if (counter == 0) { // counter is initially set to 0
                System.out.println("Please input the customer's name: ");
                input.nextLine(); // catches the menu input
                customerName = input.nextLine();
                matcher = pattern.matcher(customerName);
                counter++; // increments the counter in case the user's
                            // input is invalid
                if (!matcher.find()) { // if it has non-letter/space
                                        // characters present, throws
                                        // exception
                    throw new Exception("Try again. (Incorrect input: name must contain only letters)");
                }
            } else if (counter > 0) { // asks the user to input name again,
                                        // without the input.nextLine()
                                        // which is intended to catch the
                                        // menu int input
                System.out.println("Please input the customer's name: ");
                customerName = input.nextLine();
                matcher = pattern.matcher(customerName); // checks the input
                                                            // to ensure it
                                                            // is only
                                                            // letters
                                                            // and/or spaces
                if (!matcher.find()) {
                    throw new Exception("Try again. (Incorrect input: name must contain only letters)");
                }
            }
            continueInput = false;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    } while (continueInput);
}
```

The way you are using to "check the content of the input and start again if not suitable", works but you could do much more simple and avoid repeat yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I have a few menu options that are similar to the first one so I was trying to have a global variable that could be used for each rather than having to define them in each one. Seems to cause more problems that way.

I will do it your way, thanks!

Comment: Using variable with too broad scope causes indeed more problems that it solve them. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured out my issue.

I set the variable counter = 0; at the top of my method and then at the bottom set continueInput = true; again

Now it works as intended.

So working code looks like:

```
public void menuOptionOne() {
    counter = 0; // set counter to 0
    do {
        try {
            if (counter == 0) {
                System.out.println("Please input the customer's name: ");
                input.nextLine();
                customerName = input.nextLine();
                matcher = pattern.matcher(customerName);
                if (!matcher.find()) {
                    counter++;
                    throw new Exception("Try again. (Incorrect input: name must contain only letters)");
                }
            } else if (counter > 0) {
                System.out.println("Please input the customer's name: ");
                customerName = input.nextLine();
                matcher = pattern.matcher(customerName);
                if (!matcher.find()) {
                    throw new Exception("Try again. (Incorrect input: name must contain only letters)");
                }
            }
            continueInput = false;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    } while (continueInput);

    continueInput = true; // reset the continue input value
```